# Question marked as duplicate and voted to close after accepting other user's answer

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, deleted-answers

I asked a question on stack overflow which received 2 answers. The first answer didn't work first time, so I put a comment on it for clarification. In the meanwhile, I tried second answer's solution and it worked. I accepted the second answer.

After this, the user who gave first answer deleted his answer and then my question got the duplicate flag, plus a vote to close the question. [Here is the original post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41358597/apply-css-class-on-html-element-inside-ng-repeat-based-on-condition)

I don't know if it's appropriate to raise a question about such issue. But I felt like asking, so posted. If a question is duplicate, it should be outright marked duplicate and not because someone's answer is not accepted. Right? I would not have waited for any answer to my question if the question had duplicate flag instead of an answer (deleted after not accepting).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> If a question is duplicate, it should be outright marked duplicate and not because someone's answer is not accepted. Right?

Correct. Closing a question as a duplicate is not a "punishment", and even if it were, it would not be appropriate to "punish" someone for exercising their right to accept a different answer.

> I asked a question on stack overflow which received 2 answers. The first answer didn't work first time, so I put a comment on it for clarification. In the meanwhile, I tried second answer's solution and it worked. I accepted the second answer.

What you did here was perfectly reasonable and correct.

> After this, the user who gave first answer deleted his answer and then my question got the duplicate flag, plus a vote to close the question.

Indeed, this looks a little bit sketchy.

My first guess would be that, as he begin to do some additional research after reading your comment, he came across a duplicate question, and therefore decided to delete his answer and vote to close the question as a duplicate. This would actually be perfectly reasonable—if you come across a duplicate, you *should* flag the new question as being a duplicate and you should *not* answer duplicate questions.

However, that does not appear to be the case here… Looking at [his now-deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41358816/revisions), the [*original revision*](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41358816/1) contained a link to the proposed duplicate at the bottom, in the guise of a "more info" link. So it does look like this was retaliatory behavior on this user's part, and that he was in the wrong here. Your question was a duplicate from the outset, and since he found that duplicate *before* submitting his answer, he should have flagged it as a duplicate instead of posting an answer.

That said, you have not been hurt by this action, as having your question flagged as a duplicate is not a bad thing. Nothing really needs to be done to "fix" it, other than perhaps a moderator having a friendly conversion with Ramesh. Or perhaps he will see this Meta discussion.

If you *disagree* that your question is a duplicate of the proposed question, then you should take this opportunity to edit your question and clarify how it is different. Otherwise, you run the risk of 4 other users agreeing with Ramesh's vote and your question getting closed as a duplicate. Of course, if it *is* a duplicate, then like I said above—there's nothing wrong with having it closed as such. In fact, this is a good thing because it gets you an answer that has been already been vetted by the community.

Comment: Doesn't look *entirely* like retaliation: the question was flagged 20minutes after the answer was deleted based on [the timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41358597/timeline#review_14721169). If it were retaliation, I'd imagine it'd be flagged around the same time the answer was deleted. I could be mistaken, and this may refer to the time it entered the review queue (if not immediately), though.

Answer (score 9):

I would give a bit of slack to the responder.  I've had several times when I found a closely related question while writing my answer, posted the answer with link, and later decided that I really hadn't added much -- coming back to mark the question as a duplicate instead.

Since this is a rather short answer, I'm also more than a little suspicious, but I would not spend much time to worry about the motivation here.  You've called it to the moderators' attention, which is also correct.

N.B. I fully support Cody Gray's response.